# How to tell CiviCRM used the new font for PDF mail label printing?

Tags: pdf, address-labels

By using TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansFallbackFull.ttf", "TrueTypeUnicode");' I have successfully created the following three files droidsansfallbackfull.ctg.z, droidsansfallbackfull.z, and droidsansfallbackfull.php and copied into directory /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/tecnickcom/tcpdf/fonts.

I have added the following
$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['additional_fonts'] = 'droidsansfallbackfull'; in civicrm.settings.php. The characters have printed as square box, can someone please help, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, your setting needs to be an array:

`$civicrm_setting['CiviCRM Preferences']['additional_fonts'] = array('droidsansfallbackfull');

Then you'll need to actually set the font for the label at Administer - Communications - Label Formats. Edit the label type you're using and set the font in there.

Comment: Thanks, it works. The characters is showing what I expected, but the rest of the characters are showing as square box in the label. :(

Comment: Can you explain what "rest of characters" means?

Answer (score 0):

the rest of the characters are ordinary English characters. I did the same exercise again, but I use droidsansfallback instead of of droidsansfallbackFull, it is WORKING now, Thanks for your help!